# Максимальное число не превышающее заданное в отсортированном контейнере C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, поиск

Есть ли простой способ или встроенная функция, как lower_bound, но которая вернёт указатель на максимальное число не превышающее X?

К примеру:

```
vector<int> {2,3,5,7,9,11}
```

Я хочу найти максимальное число не превышающее 8 и получить итератор на элемент со значением 7.

Comment: `upper_bound` и перейти на один элемент влево? Только контейнер должен быть отсортирован.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В библиотеке `algorithm` есть такая функция, как `std::lower_bound`, которая принимает в качестве трёх аргументов итератор на начало контейнера, итератор на конец контейнера и значение X. Возвращает итератор на первое число, которое не удовлетворяет условию X > *it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
    cout << *(--lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), 8));
```

Comment: Если `std::lower_bound` не найдет нужный элемент, то он возвращает `std::end`, это тоже нужно обработать